# Numerical solution to integro-differential equation (Wigner Weisskopf Problem)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-electrodynamics, computational-physics, differential-equations, cavity-qed

The time dynamics of an atom interacting with a reservoir of spectral density $J(\omega)$ are obtained by solving the following integro-differential equation $[1]$:

$$ \dot{c}(t) = \int_0^t dt'\int_0^{\infty}d\omega J(\omega)e^{i(\omega_0-\omega)(t-t')}c(t') $$

This can be solved analytically, for example when $J(\omega)$ is Lorentzian $[1]$. But how could I solve this numerically (in python), given $J(\omega)$ as an array of data? Is it always possible?

References:

$[1]$: $\textit{The Theory of Open Quantum Systems, Petruccione, Breuer p468}$

Comment: Are you asking how to find numerical solution of this equation? I think this is not a good question here, because it is mostly about numerical methods and computer skills... No physics in this.

Answer (score 1):

This equation can be solved via Laplace transforms, which is even possible in a semi-analytical fashion without direct numerical schemes such as discretization. See e.g. https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.89.033820 .